# python-How do I plot from a list of lists imported from Excel?

Tags: python-3.x, list

Helo everyone. My task sounds simple but I feel myself confused. I have got an Excel file with five different columns (Magnitude, BP1, BP2, D1, D2) each with the same number of rows (23).

Input:
Five columns with numerical data.

Desired output:
Two subplots. First one must contain Magnitude vs Frequency (understanding frequency as a line from BP1 to BP2 for every magnitude item). Second one must be Magnitude vs Distance (understanding distance in a similar manner as above).

Tried coding:

```
import numpy as numpy
import os, sys
import os.path
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fname=os.path.join(workingdir, 'Frequency and BP values.xlsx')
if not os.path.isfile(fname):
    sys.exit('File missing: '+fname)

f_read=pd.read_excel(fname, sheet_name='Valores')
```

```
#Reading columns
Magnitude=f_read['Magnitude (Mw)'].tolist()
BP1=f_read['BP1'].tolist()
BP2=f_read['BP2'].tolist()
D1=f_read['Distance1'].tolist()
D2=f_read['Distance2'].tolist()

#Building lists
Feq_Mag=[BP1, BP2]
for i in range(0, 23):
    Feq_Mag0=[x[i] for x in Feq_Mag]
D_Mag=[D1, D2]
D_Mag=[x[0] for x in D_Mag]

#Plotting attributes
#---Frequency plot
fig=plt.figure()
Freq_plot=fig.add_subplot(121)
Freq_plot.set_xlabel(u'Frequency (Hz)', fontsize=6)
Freq_plot.set_ylabel(u'Magnitude (Mw)', fontsize=6)
Freq_plot.plot(BP_Mag, c='crimson', linewidth=2.5)
plt.show()
new_dir=os.chdir(catdir)
fig.savefig('Ranges_Distribution.png')
plt.close('all')
```

Actual output:
A single line is plotted and it does not even correspond to the magnitude value. It is plotted at base level.

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong?
I would suggest that you isolate the problematic part of your code and resubmit the question.
Regarding plotting with multidimensional lists, in general: (unless you're dealing with  [surfaces or meshgrids](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html)) you really don't need to construct a multidimensional list or array in order to plot something. Occam's razor and all that. Just call `plt.plot` with two separate 1D lists with the same length.

Comment: So i don't need to build a multidimensional list to plot it? Ok, so i just call plt.plot, will this plot a line between BP1 and BP2 for each magnitude value? This is what's going wrong. Maybe I can send you a pic of my desired plot and my original data.

Comment: I think I understand the problem now. Gimme a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, so if I understand correctly: you have one set of *x*-values and two sets of corresponding *y*-values (let's call them *y1* and *y2*). You want to take these values and draw a line from *y1* to *y2* for each *x*. In that case, you want to run a for-loop. Written as a 2-D list, and using only lists and `matplotlib.pyplot`, this is what I came up with.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
     [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]]
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

some_figure = plt.figure()
some_subplot = some_figure.add_subplot('111')
for i in range(len(x)):
    some_subplot.plot([x[i], x[i]], [y[0][i], y[1][i]])

plt.show()
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Yes, it is actually a set of Y-values and two corresponding x-values. Thank you very much for your help!